# RHEL 5.1 loses changes to /etc/hosts above lines for `localhost`

Tags: rhel5, hosts, hp-server-automation

Is there a known fix (other than upgrading from 5.1) to fix `/etc/hosts` from being replaced on reboot?

I discovered this behavior when running HP's Server Automation tools. HPSA sets-up a variety of local aliases for itself to use for different components to communicate wit each other.

However, after reboot, the hosts files is reverted to a quasi-plain-vanilla version: all lines above the entry for `localhost` are removed. Manually re-adding those needed lines below the entries for `localhost` works, but is non-ideal.

Is there a fix for this behavior?

---

<sub><sup>I do realize that RHEL 5u1 is not officially supported for HPSA 7.8, but the hosts file resetting is not good for a variety of other reasons, too.</sup></sub>

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a custom script running on the host resetting the host file ? That look like your security department is playing in your back.

Comment: @Fleole - there *may* be .. I don't see anything, though. The boxes I've seen this on have their firewall and selinux disabled (segmented network for testing purposes). Also - 5.3 and 5.5 do not exhibit the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ultimate fix for this was to move to a newer release of RHEL (5.3 or 5.5, depending on the use).

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable kudzu.

Try first

chkconfig --levels 345 kudzu off

or

chkconfig kudzu --del

Comment: how does the pre-cursor to HAL alter the `/etc/hosts` file?